# What does this definition mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

$B$ is a $3x3$ matrix

Calculate the matrix $C :=$
$[(e_1)_B
(e_2)_B
(e_3)_B]
$
, where
$(e_j)_B$

denotes the coordinate vector
of $e_j$ ∈ Q3
relative to the columns of $B$.

I don't understand what $C$ is, can someone provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2D example. Say $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$
and $e_1  = \binom{1}{0},e_2=\binom{0}{1}$. Write the collumns of $B$ as $b_1,b_2$. Then note that
\begin{align}
e_1 &= 0b_1 + 1b_2\\
e_2 &= 1b_1 - 1b_2
\end{align}
so the coordinates of $e_1$ relative to $b_1,b_2$ are $\color{red}{\binom{0}{1}}$ and for $e_2$ its $\color{blue}{\binom{1}{-1}}$. So
$$ C = \begin{pmatrix}\color{red}0 & \color{blue}1 \\ \color{red}1& \color{blue}{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
(I would have used the transpose of $C$, but nevermind...) The usefulness of $C$, is if you had any vector expressed in standard coordinates $e_1,e_2$, you can multiply by $C^T$ on the left, or multiply by $C$ on the right, to convert them to $b_1,b_2$ coordinates. For example if $v = \binom{5}{-2}$, then
$$ C^Tv = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1& -1\end{pmatrix}\binom{5}{-2} = \binom{-2}{7}$$
and sure enough, $$-2 b_1 + 7 b_2 = -2\binom{1}{1} + 7 \binom 10 = \binom 5{-2}.$$